# New Button is Missing in Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager

Tags: android, button, virtual-device-manager

I've just installed the Android SDK & Eclipse. I created the first simple app. The problem I have is that the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager does not have the **New** button as indicated on [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html).

I do have the **Create** button. I tried to create a *virtual device* but after I filled in all the selections the **OK** button was still grayed out. The problem is that I cannot create a virtual device. Does any know why the **New** button is not available?

Comment: Show us screenshot of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There Will Be **Create** button because you are creating First AVD... 
After you create one AVD then there will be **New Button**......

While Creating AVD... make sure that you have filled all fields with valid information.....
then OK button will be ENABLED to use...

Follow this image for filling data For AVD...

[image]

This may help you...

Comment: Solved it for me.  Thanks for the picture!

Answer (score 0):

There are two tabs in the AVD Manager. ***Android Virtual Devices*** is the tab with all the emulators you have created and can launch to test Android apps on & ***Device Definitions*** is the tab where you can create new definitions for devices.

You can create new device definitions for devices under the *Device Definitions* tab using the **New Device** option. You may then choose to use the said definition or an existing definition and create a new emulator using the **Create AVD** option under the *Device Definitions* tab or the **New** option under the *Android Virtual Devices* tab.

That said, it'd be helpful to understand the problem if you could provide screenshots of it.